# Fixing visualisation of a hitbox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an Unity2D game with a view from above. I have a code, that visualises my hitbox. But it only visualises one side of it. Idea of my hitbox is that it is a trapezoid with one side that is semicircle. How do I do that? (The first line starts right in front of my character, the semicircle ends right at radius, and the other two lines just complete the figure.)
Here's my current code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float attackRadius = 2f;
    public float maxAngle = 40f;
    private bool isAttacking = false;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.05f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.05f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isAttacking)
        {
            isAttacking = true;
            Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            cursorPosition.z = 0f;

            Vector3 direction = cursorPosition - transform.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            DrawHitbox(angle);

            Invoke("FinishAttack", 0.1f);
        }
    }

    void DrawHitbox(float angle)
    {
        int numSegments = 100; 
        float angleStep = (2 * maxAngle)

        lineRenderer.positionCount = numSegments + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numSegments; i++)
        {
            float currentAngle = angle - maxAngle + angleStep * i;
            float x = Mathf.Cos(currentAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * attackRadius;
            float y = Mathf.Sin(currentAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * attackRadius;
            Vector3 point = transform.position + new Vector3(x, y, 0f);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, point);
        }
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(numSegments, lineRenderer.GetPosition(0));
    }

    void FinishAttack()
    {
        isAttacking = false;
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
    }
}
```